# Datatables get filter text input string

Tags: jquery, datatables, filtering

I have a Datatable that loads with new data every time the user changes the option from a dropdown list for which I want to keep the same filter even even if the table content changes. I've tried to get the current value from the search input by using:

```
$('div.dataTables_filter input').val()
```

suggested in `https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/242/getting-filter-text`

or

```
table = $("#datatable-buttons").DataTable({...});
table.fnSettings().oPreviousSearch;
```

but without any success :( Is there a way to get the filter input text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `search()` without params, then it return the current filter

```js
var filter = table.search()
```

or you kan keep on track of the current search by using the search.dt event :

```js
table.on('search.dt', function() {
  var input = $('.dataTables_filter input')[0];
  console.log(input.value)
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/44datL5b/**

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot! I didn't had any idea that the only thing to do was just to type .search() :)